# Android execution error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator

The app compiles correctly but I have this error log LogCat when I try to execute the app whether I do execute on an emulator or a real device:

```
> 03-10 16:01:40.112: E/AndroidRuntime(901): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 03-10
> 16:01:40.112: E/AndroidRuntime(901): java.lang.RuntimeException:
> Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{dz.makika.mymaps/dz.makika.mymaps.MainActivity}:
> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error
> inflating class fragment 03-10 16:01:40.112: E/AndroidRuntime(901):
>   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
> 03-10 16:01:40.112: E/AndroidRuntime(901):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
> 03-10 16:01:40.112: E/AndroidRuntime(901):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 03-10
> 16:01:40.112: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
> 03-10 16:01:40.112: E/AndroidRuntime(901):    at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 03-10
> 16:01:40.112: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 03-10 16:01:40.112:
> E/AndroidRuntime(901):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 03-10
> 16:01:40.112: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 03-10
> 16:01:40.112: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 03-10 16:01:40.112:
> E/AndroidRuntime(901):    at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
> 03-10 16:01:40.112: E/AndroidRuntime(901):    at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 03-10
> 16:01:40.112: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 03-10 16:01:40.112:
> E/AndroidRuntime(901): Caused by: android.view.InflateException:
> Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment 03-10
> 16:01:40.112: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
> 03-10 16:01:40.112: E/AndroidRuntime(901):    at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 03-10
> 16:01:40.112: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 03-10
> 16:01:40.112: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 03-10
> 16:01:40.112: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 03-10
> 16:01:40.112: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at
> com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
> 03-10 16:01:40.112: E/AndroidRuntime(901):    at
> android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895) 03-10
> 16:01:40.112: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at
> dz.makika.mymaps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17) 03-10
> 16:01:40.112: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at
> android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133) 03-10
> 16:01:40.112: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
> 03-10 16:01:40.112: E/AndroidRuntime(901):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
> 03-10 16:01:40.112: E/AndroidRuntime(901):    ... 11 more 03-10
> 16:01:40.112: E/AndroidRuntime(901): Caused by:
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's
> AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4242000
> but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the
> <application> element:     <meta-data
> android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
> android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" /> 03-10
> 16:01:40.112: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at
> com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.n(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Post the xml you are inflating in onCreate() of MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="17"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="xx.Xxx.XXX.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSy..." />
</application>
```